# browser crashes if I build android without GPS

Tags: android, crash, gps

Can someone please tell me where to look out for in the code to check if GPS is enabled or disabled?

My browser crashes if I build android without GPS (customised one). This happens when I try to open a webpage that tries to acquire location, like in Google homepage.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, GPS is one of requirements for Android platform. I guess you need to make some dummy module that will act as a false GPS.

Answer (score 0):

```
String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),  Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
if(provider != null ){      
        if(! provider.contains("gps")){    
               //GPS is disabled..prompt the user to enable GPS...
               //you can also start an intent to send the user to the settings page..
               Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 5);
            }

}
```

Use onActivityResult to see if the user has enabled GPS...